Randomized Trace Estimation
I was reading a blog post on concentration inequalities in applied mathematics (source: Ethan Epperly's blog), and I encountered a step involving Bernstein's inequality that I am struggling to understand. The specific inequality in question is:
$$
\mathbb{P}\left\{\left|T_k-\operatorname{tr}(M)\right| \geq t\right\} \leq 2 \exp \left(-\frac{k t^2}{4\|M\|_{\mathrm{F}}^2+4 / 3 \cdot \operatorname{tn}\|M\|}\right)
$$
which implies:
$$
k \geq\left(\frac{4\|M\|_{\mathrm{F}}^2}{\epsilon^2}+\frac{4 n\|M\|}{3 \epsilon}\right) \log \left(\frac{2}{\delta}\right)
$$
I am having difficulty understanding how Bernstein's inequality is applied in deriving these results. Could someone provide a detailed explanation or derivation of how Bernstein's inequality is utilized here?
Thank you for your assistance.

Let $Y = x^{\top} M x$, where $x$ is as defined in the blog.
To apply the Bernstein inequality, we need to find (an upper bound on) the following quantities: (i) A value $B$ such that $|Y - \mathbb{E}[Y]| \leq B$, almost surely and (ii) $\sigma^2$ := Var$(Y)$. Let us begin with bounding $B$. We have,
\begin{align*}
|Y - \mathbb{E}[Y]| \leq \sup_{x} |x^{\top} M x| + |\text{tr}(M)| \leq \|M\|_2 \sup_{x} x^{\top}x + n \|M\|_2 \leq n \|M\|_2 + n \|M\|_2 = 2n \|M\|_2,
\end{align*}
where we use the relations $|\text{tr}(M)| \leq n \|M\|_2$ and $x^{\top}x = n$ (based on the definition of the random vector $x$).
To obtain a bound on the variance of $Y$, a simple approach is to use the Efros Stein inequality. Let $x^{(i)}$ be random vector whose all but the $i^{\text{th}}$ coordinates are the same as that of $x$ and the $i^{\text{th}}$ coordinate is $z_i$, a Rademacher random variable (takes values in $\{-1,1\}$ with equal probability), independent of $x$. Let $Y^{(i)} = [x^{(i)}]^{\top} M x^{(i)}$. Then Efros Stein inequality states that
\begin{align*}
\text{Var}(Y) \leq \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i = 1}^n \mathbb{E}[(Y - Y^{(i)})^2].
\end{align*}
If $x_i$ denotes the $i^{\text{th}}$ coordinate of $x$, then
\begin{align*}
Y - Y^{(i)} = \sum_{j = 1, j \neq i}^n M_{ij}x_j(x_i - z_i).
\end{align*}
This follows by noting that $x$ and $x^{(i)}$ are identical on all coordinates except the $i^{\text{th}}$ one and hence only that features in the summation. Also, since $M_{ii}x_i^2 = M_{ii}z_i^2$, that term is not included in the above summation. Consequently,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[(Y - Y^{(i)})^2] & = \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{j = 1, j \neq i}^n M_{ij}x_j(x_i - z_i)\right]^2 \\
& = \sum_{j = 1, j \neq i}^n M_{ij}^2 \mathbb{E}[x_j^2(x_i - z_i)^2] \\
& = \sum_{j = 1, j \neq i}^n M_{ij}^2 \mathbb{E}[(x_i - z_i)^2] \\
& = 2\sum_{j = 1, j \neq i}^n M_{ij}^2,
\end{align*}
where the second step uses the fact that $x_j$ and $x_{j'}$ are independent and zero mean. Thus,
\begin{align*}
\text{Var}(Y) \leq  \sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 1, j \neq i}^n M_{ij}^2 \leq \sum_{i,j = 1}^n M_{ij}^2 = \|M\|_F^2.
\end{align*}
Seems like the author used another technique to obtain a looser bound of  $\sigma^2 \leq 4\|M\|_F^2$. On plugging these relations into Eqn.(9) in the blog you obtain the first equation in the post. The second follows by plugging the value of $k$ in the first and some basic algebra.
